# iOS Network Extension error creating TUN/TAP interface SIOCGIFMTU failed: device not configured

Tags: swift, vpn, networkextension

Currently working on a Network Extension that lets me stablish a connection using a VPN using a `.ovpn` file, by using [OpenVPNAdapter](https://github.com/ss-abramchuk/OpenVPNAdapter) library. I have saved correcly my configuration to the System settings and when running the extension to perform debug my extension status changes from disconnected, stays in connecting for a while and then disconnects. Further inspecting the console logs for the device anf filtering by the network extension I get three main error messages.

> Log message from provider: TUN Error: cannot acquire tun interface socket
>
> SIOCGIFMTU failed: Device not configured
>
> NEVirtualInterfaceAdjustReadBufferSize: interface_get_mtu failed (6), defaulting to max mtu

I don't know where to head now as I am debugging the network extension using the Console from the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to solve this on my own. I created a Packet Tunnel Network Extension and in my PacketTunnelProvider class came the problems. It did not crash so setting up the debugger in that class was not worth it. I ran my target and started my app and set several NSLogs in the functions so I could see in the device's console what was happening. My problem was that I tried to set a nil value in a dictionary for a key thus terminating the extension. That crash message can easily be seen in the console.

The problem was when extending `PacketTunnelProvider` with `OpenVPNAdapterDelegate` in the function to configure the tunnel

```
func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, configureTunnelWithNetworkSettings networkSettings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings?, completionHandler: @escaping (OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow?) -> Void) {
    networkSettings?.dnsSettings?.matchDomains = [""];
}
```

Previously I had `networkSettings.dnsSettings?.matchDomains = [""];` so `networkSettings` was unwrapped and it was `nil` making it crash the extension and the tunnel not being able to get connected.